# Unsatisfied Link Error on x86 (intel atom) Android emulator (avd)

Tags: android, x86, emulation, android-virtual-device, android-x86

I am trying to run my app in the new (intel-accelerated) x86 emulator and getting an unsatisfied link error due to a native library. It uses some .so file which is normally placed under libs/armeabi. I am not sure how this file gets picked up; presumably since this is an x86 platform, it should be under libs/x86 ... but still unsatisfied link. Is there some other directory I should put the .so in to be recognized?

Comment: Is this for Google TV? The current Android NDK does not produce valid library files for x86 GTV.